# ROS on Ubuntu XX.10 versions

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, installation, ros-kinetic, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is ROS installation supported on Ubuntu xx.10 (16.10, 18.10, 20.10) versions ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/367592/ros-on-ubuntu-xx.10-versions/) by [electrophod](https://answers.ros.org/users/43169/electrophod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 277 on 2020-12-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

(You tagged this `melodic` and `kinetic`, so I'll answer for ROS 1, but the same would apply to ROS 2)

The answer will depend a bit on what you mean by "is ROS installation supported":

- if you are asking whether you can use `apt` to install ROS using binary packages provided by the ROS buildfarm, then: no, ROS binary packages are typically only provided for Ubuntu LTS releases
- if your question was actually whether it would be possible to install ROS using whatever means, then: maybe. You could try building it from source. This is a *maybe*, as it's possible you'll run into issues with dependencies having changed between officially supported OS and your target OS, which may require patches to the sources

For information on which specific platform + OS combinations are supported:

- ROS 1: [REP-3: Target Platforms](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html)
- ROS 2: [REP-2000: ROS 2 Releases and Target Platforms](https://ros.org/reps/rep-2000.html)

Each ROS release lists the Ubuntu (and other OS) versions for which official support is provided.

To run ROS applications on OS which are not officially supported, Docker is often used.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2